# Change labels in highcharter sankey

Tags: r, highcharts, sankey-diagram, r-highcharter

I want to improve the appearance of my highcharter sankey diagram.

The **labels of the nodes should be left and right to the plot** and not "on" the nodes. So in the plot shown below the country names should appear left and right to the plot.

Additionally I am failing to add a **thousand separator ","** to the labels showing up when hovering over links and nodes.

This is the code I use for the sankey plot:

```
highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df_list_spaces,
    nodes = nodes_list,
    links = df_list_spaces,
    name = "assets",
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = TRUE
      ))
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

To add a thousand separator I tried this:

```
# change thousands sep
hcoptslang <- getOption("highcharter.lang")
hcoptslang$thousandsSep <- ","
options(highcharter.lang = hcoptslang)
```

This works for other highcharter objects but strangely not for the "sankey" chart.

To **reproduce the plot** I also add the code with all the data transformation needed. There are probably nicer ways to end up with the final data for the plot but this is how I did it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

df <- tibble(from = c("Brazil", "Brazil", "Poland", "Spain", "Poland"),
             toto = c("Portugal", "Spain", "Portugal", "Brazil", "Poland"),
             assets = c(5324523.4523, 232452345.234, 2345234.52345, 3234523.45234, 63452345.2345))


# bring rows into lists
# add space at the end for values of "to" 

transform_to_list <- function(data, from, to, weight, add_spaces = FALSE) {
  
  df_list <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    
    df_list[[i]] <- list(from = data[[from]][i],
                  # add spaces, so there is a difference between "from" and "to" countries
                     to = ifelse(test = add_spaces == TRUE, 
                                 yes = paste0(data[[to]][i], " "), 
                                 no = data[[to]][i]  
                                 ),
                     weight = data[[weight]][i]
                  )
  }
  
  return(df_list)
}

# select the data set, from, to and weight column; add_spaces = TRUE is needed for Sankey diagramms,
# for other things, for example "dependency_wheels" add_spaces should be FALSE

df_list_spaces <- transform_to_list(data = df, from = "from", "toto", weight = "assets", add_spaces = TRUE)

#--------------------------------------

# next step is to attach colors to the countries, but the problem is that we had to add spaces to the "to"
# countries and hence we have to find a way to attach the same color for example for "Brazil" and "Brazil ".


# We do this with a little function:

# inputs: data, from column, to column and a colorpallete
transform_to_nodes_list <- function(data, from, to, colors) {
  
  # create a vector of unique values from the "from" column
  from_col <- unique(data[[from]])
  
  # create a vector of values from the "to" column, with a space added at the end
  to_col <- unique(paste0(data[[to]], " "))
  
  # combine the "from" and "to" columns into a single vector
  id_col <- c(from_col, to_col)
  
  # create a "helper" column that ignores spaces at the end of values in the "id" column
  helper_col <- gsub("\\s+$", "", id_col) 
  
  # match colors based on helper column, first create factors, 
  # then change class to numeric so first factor gets first color of the color palette, second factor second color..   
  color_col <- colors[as.numeric(factor(helper_col))]
  
  # not necessary step
  d0 <- tibble(id_col, color_col)
  
  nodes_list <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(d0)) {
    
    # from <- deparse(substitute(from))
    # to <- deparse(substitute(to))
    # weight <- deparse(substitute(weight))
    
    nodes_list[[i]] <- list(id = d0[["id_col"]][i],
                            color = d0[["color_col"]][i])
  }
  
  
  return(nodes_list)
}

#  color palette:
pal <- c("brown", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "red")


# call the functions:
df_list_spaces <- transform_to_list(data = df, from = "from", "toto", weight = "assets", add_spaces = TRUE)

nodes_list <- transform_to_nodes_list(data = df, from = "from", to = "toto", colors = pal)

# and finally plot
highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df_list_spaces,
    nodes = nodes_list,
    links = df_list_spaces,
    name = "assets",
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = TRUE
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
library(purrr) ## convenient conversion of dataframe rows to lists

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3))
  ) |>
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function () { return '<b>' +
                             this.point.from + ' -> ' +
                             this.point.to + '</b><br /> ' +
                             Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.weight)
                            }"
                            )
             )
```

Formatting of tooltips (thousands separator) adopted from here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885998/20513099](https://%20%20##%20taken%20from:%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885998/20513099)

Haven't found out yet how to align the node labels though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I am not able to run your code, but the reason for this is maybe an oversight on my side.. I end up with a R console hang.. Seems like R is stuck in the JS function, but I am not familiar with this so I dont find a way out..

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to use `df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3)` as highchart data (without `node_list` etc.), because the `pmap` expression creates row-wise lists of (from, to, weight) as required.